# What's the correct way of displaying ViewPager after associated ListView's item click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm a beginner in Android, so I apologize for the mistakes and I'd appreciate any constructive criticism.

I'm writing a basic application with a ListView of images, and when the user clicks on an item in the list, I want to display that image in a ViewPager, where the user can swipe back and forth to browse the whole list of images. Afterwards when the user presses the back button, I want to switch back to the ListView.

I manage the business logic in the MainActivity, which uses MainActivityFragment for the ListView and ImageHolderFragment for ViewPager.

The simplified code so far is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mListItemAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_item_name, mListItems);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_content);
    mListView.setAdapter(mListItemAdapter);

    mDeletedListItems = new ArrayList<>();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_display, null, true);
    mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mListItems);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                setContentView(mViewPager);  // TODO: this is very wrong!
            }
        });

    loadImages();
    noContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_content_text);
    if (mListItems.isEmpty()) {
        noContentText.setText(R.string.no_images);
    } else {
        mImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Although this does work to some extent, meaning that it manages to display the ViewPager when an item in the list is clicked, there are two things about it ringing the alarm bells:

- I've read that calling setContentView() for the second time in the same class is pretty much a sin. Nobody explained me why.
- The back button doesn't work in this case. When it's pressed, the application is terminated instead of going back to the list view. I believe this is connected to the first point.

I would appreciate any help, explanations if my idea is completely wrong, and if my case is hopeless, I'd like to see a successful combination of ListView and ViewPager with transitions between each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity already has `R.layout.activity_main` set as content view, which rightly displays the list view - that's what the responsibility of this activity is as you defined it. If we want to change what's shown on the screen, we should use a different instance of a building block (activity or fragment) to display the view pager images.

To say the least, imagine if you wanted to change the view to a third piece of functionality or UI, or a fourth... it would be a nightmare to maintain, extend and test as you're not separating functionality into manageable units. Fields that are needed in one view are mixed with those needed in another, your class file would grow larger and larger as each view brings its click listeners, callbacks, etc., you'd also have to override the back button so it does what you want - it's just not how the Android framework was designed to help you. And what if you wanted to re-use UI components in different contexts whilst tapping in to the framework's activity lifecycle callbacks? That's why [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) were introduced.

In your case, the list view could continue to run in your `MainActivity` and in your click listener, `onItemClick` you could start a new activity that will hold a viewPager:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyLargePhotoActivityPager.class);
i.putExtra(KEY_POSITION, position);
// pass the data too
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Notice how you could pass the position to this activity as an `int` extra, in order for that second activity to nicely set the viewPager to the position that the user clicked on. I'll let you discover how to build the second activity and put the ViewPager there. You also get back button functionality assuming your [launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) are set accordingly, if needed. One thing to note is that when you do come back to the list View, you'd probably want to scroll to the position from the view pager, which is why you could supply that back [as a result via a request code](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). The returned position can be supplied back to the list view.

Alternatively, you could use the same activity but have two fragments (see the link further above) and have an equivalent outcome. In fact, one of your fragments could store the list view, and the second fragment could be a fullscreen `DialogFragment` that stores a viewPager, like a photo gallery (some details [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-unravel-the-mystery-of-androids-full-screen-dialog-fragments/)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but I'm loading the images from the storage in the first screen in order to create the list with thumbnails, then I would have to do it again from scratch in the second activity in order to actually display those images, or is there any other way around it?

Comment: You wouldn't really redo any work since it sounds like you need the original/larger size in the second screen, so you'd have to load a different image altogether. How are you loading the thumbnails in the first place? You can use something like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#how-do-i-use-glide) to populate your `ImageView` that is part of the layout in each ViewPager slot.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that calling setContentView() for the second time in the
>   same class is pretty much a sin. Nobody explained me why.

Well, you kind of get an idea as to why. 
When you use `setContentView()` to display another 'screen' you do no have a proper back stack. 
You also keep references to Views (like `mListView`) that are not visible anymore and are therefore kind of 'useless' after you `setContentView()` for the second time. 
Also keep in mind orientation changes or your app going to the background - you'll have to keep track of the state that your Activity was in which is way more complicated than it has to be if you have one Activity that does two different things.

You won't be arrested for doing things like you do right now, but it's just harder to debug and keep bug free.

I'd suggest using two different Activities for the two different things that you want to do, or use one Activity and two Fragments, swapping them back and forth.

If you insist on having it all in one Activity you need to override `onBackPressed()` (called when the user presses the back button) and restore the first state of your Activity (`setContentView()` again, pretty much starting all over).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, overriding the onBackPressed() method was the first thing I tried actually, I get an `InflateException: Error inflating class fragment` in that case. I was hoping to change views just using fragments, but that didn't work either. The other points you made are also valid, I have a lot to learn.